# React Native BottomTabNavigator remove white space

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm facing a problem with my Bottom Tab Navigator. I get a white space between my tabs and the end of the screen of my iPhone 11 Simulator. On a iPhone 8 Simulator I don't have these white space. There is also a small white space above the Tabs. How can I remove this space? I'm not able to find a solution and I'm running out of time. Thanks![image]

[image]

This is my implementation so far:

## DetailsNavigation.js

```
  const DetailsNavigation = ({ route }) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeBackgroundColor: colors.primary,
        activeTintColor: colors.secondary,
        inactiveBackgroundColor: colors.secondary,
        inactiveTintColor: colors.primary,
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 13,
          marginBottom: 5,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="DetailsScreen"
        options={{
          title: "Portfolio",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialIcons name="account-box" size={24} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
        children={() => <DetailsScreen worker={route.params} />}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="RatingScreen"
        component={RatingScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Bewertungen",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialIcons name="star" size={24} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
export default DetailsNavigation;
```

DetailsNavigation.js is implemented here:

## WorkersNavigation.js

```
const WorkersNavigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="WelcomeScreen"
        component={WelcomeScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      ></Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="WorkersScreen"
        component={WorkersScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      ></Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="DetailsNavigation"
        component={DetailsNavigation}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      ></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default WorkersNavigation;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are wrap   outside of WorkersNavigation like this

```
<SafeAreaView> 
<WorkersNavigation /> 
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 11):

The `white space` found on iPhone X devices and above is called the Safe Area and exists to ensure appropriate insetting based on the device and context. Refer to the official [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/) for more information.

The react-navigation's BottomTabNavigator supports safe areas out-of-the-box for the [default BottomTabBar](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/packages/bottom-tabs/src/views/BottomTabBar.tsx), so in order to remove the SafeArea under it, you need to override the settings provided for the BottomTabNavigator.

```
<Tab.Navigator
    tabBarOptions={ {
        ...
        safeAreaInsets: {
            bottom: 0,
        },
    } }
>
...
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    screenOptions={({route}) => ({
    tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: '#436332', borderTopColor: '#23321A'},
    tabBarLabelStyle: {
      fontWeight: '600',
      fontSize: 12,
    },
    tabBarActiveTintColor: '#f1c522',
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#f4f1de',
    tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: '#436332',
    tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: '#436332',
  })}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines at your TabNavigator screenOptions:

```
tabBarItemStyle: {borderWidth: 1, borderColor:'#101010'},
tabBarStyle: {paddingBottom:0, backgroundColor: '#101010'},
```

and if you use <SafeAreaView>, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for remove bottom space I need to set the height for **tabBarStyle** and also for **tabBarItemStyle**:

```
<Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName={ScreenNames.Home}
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarItemStyle: {
          height: 53,
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          height: 53,
        },
      }}>
```

For remove upper white space:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName={ScreenNames.Home}
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarStyle: {
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      elevation: 0,
    },
  }}>
```